# Display action sheet on OnBackButtonPressed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating xamarin form using PCL. I want to provide a feature when user press backbutton from mobile device hardware then i want to `DispalyActionSheet`. Is any option that i can do that. Below is my sample code.

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackButtonPressed();

        //new thread
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
              var action = await DisplayActionSheet("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Facebook", "twitter", "Instagram");

      //  Here i want to get  action  result for next step
        });

        return true; // 
    }
```

**Code update as per suggested by Martin Zikmund**  : Feeling difficulty on redirect on different page after code execution

```
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            bool returnvalue = true;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
              vawait DisplayActionSheet("ActionSheet: Send to?", "null", null, "Facebook", "twitter", "Instagram");
                    switch (action)
                    {
                        case "Facebook":
                         // My code
                CallPage();  Here i want to redirect on different page 
               break;
                    }
            });
      }


 public async void CallPage()
    {
        try
        {
            await RetrunToPreviousPage();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //throw;
        }
    }

  public async Task<dynamic> RetrunToPreviousPage()
    {

            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new InboundOrderList(), this);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();            

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle the back button yourself, you will need to remove the call to `base.OnBackButtonPressed`.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{        
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
          var action = await DisplayActionSheet(
            "ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Facebook", "twitter", "Instagram");

          //your logic             
    });

    return true; //you handled the back button press
}
```

When you actually want to navigate back within your logic, you will have to pop the page manually of the stack:

```
await this.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

### Update

You still have to return `true` at the end of `OnBackButtonPressed` to mark it as handled. Additionally, `ReturnToPreviousPage` does not need any `return true;` and the return type can be a simple `Task`:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        bool returnvalue = true;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
          vawait DisplayActionSheet("ActionSheet: Send to?", "null", null, "Facebook", "twitter", "Instagram");
                switch (action)
                {
                    case "Facebook":
                     // My code
            CallPage();  Here i want to redirect on different page 
           break;
                }
        });
      return true; // always return true
  }

  ...

  public async Task RetrunToPreviousPage()
  { 
      Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new InboundOrderList(), this);
      await Navigation.PopAsync();            
  }
```

Comment: getting issue to redirect on page after //your logic   i create a function CallPage(); public   async void CallPage()
        {  await RetrunToPreviousPage(); }  and in public async Task<dynamic> RetrunToPreviousPage()
        {
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new UserManifestInboundOrder(), this);
await Navigation.PopAsync();
       return true;
        }

Comment: what i am doing mistake

Comment: Please update the original update with the new code so I can see what is called where :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer, if that does not solve the issue you are having, please describe the problem :-)

Comment: Where you are calling the function RetrunToPreviousPage()

Comment: I meant you should keep `CallPage` method as it is.

Comment: i understand. Thanks for your help